# fetching multiple repositories shallowly into one workspace results in an error

Tags: git

Why is it that fetching 2 git repositories with `--depth=1` (shallow clone) into one workspace gives an error:

```
fatal: did not find object for shallow 6885f7a1d032df25195fb56a7c1a64049a19cd62
```

These are the statements done (copied from jenkins output, but manually fetching results in the same error), omitting the adding of the remotes:

```
git init c:\workspace
git -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress ssh://developer@***/bar +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/bar/* --depth=1
git -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress ssh://developer@***/foo +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/foo/* --depth=1
```

Fetching the 2 repositories without the --depth option works fine.

I notice that after the first fetch a text file 'shallow' is created in the .git folder, with a bunch of commit ids, the one in the error is one of them. I think that normally when fetching again from the same repository, Git uses these commitids to tell the remote what refs it knows, but in this case it is sending the commitids of one repo to another one, and thus failing.

How can I get this to work?

Comment: can you post the lines that you execute

Comment: I have copied the lines from our Jenkins output (obfuscated sensitive info). When I perform the fetches manually on a command prompt I get the same result as in Jenkins, so Jenkins isn't part of the problem.

Comment: Why do use the refs? do you know what it does? `+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/bar/*`

Comment: It's what Jenkins generates, and I need to get this working on Jenkins so that's how I have been trying it. Without it fetching doesn't work either: fatal: Couldn't find remote ref HEAD. I think that's because of how we use Git at our company. You think it's relevant?

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing your additional information i'm recommending you to add 2 origins to your repo and then fetch them.

```
git remote add bar ...
git remote add bar ...

git fetch bar ... --depth=1
git fetch foo ... --depth=1
```